# cordova-plugin-facebook4 - iOS build fails with error code 65, probably because of missing native dependencies

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap

`phonegap build ios` fails with the following error message:

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dtsdztgswtsnnubosnumqjssdpaj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp\ App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp\ App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FacebookConnectPlugin.o /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyApp/platforms/ios/MyApp\ App/Plugins/cordova-plugin-facebook4/FacebookConnectPlugin.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Command finished with error code 65: xcodebuild -workspace,MyApp.xcworkspace,-scheme,MyApp,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11 Pro Max,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyApp/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch


(node:3817) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyApp/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)

(node:3817) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3817) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

These are my plugin versions:

- phonegap cli: 8.0.0
- cordova-ios: 5.0.1
- phonegap-plugin-facebook4: 6.2.0

Additional Context

I managed to solve the issue by manually editing my Podfile and adding the following lines to it, then running `cd platforms/ios && pod install`:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

After that, phonegap build ios completed succesfully.

Could it be that somehow native dependencies aren't being added?
It would be ideal not having to add these back every time I remove and re-add the platform, and adding them in a build hook sounds veeeeeeery hacky.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i have permission related issue so that's why i give permission to `($user)/.cocoapods` but not working

then i have delete that folder and then `pod install` command fire in `($app_folder)/platform/ios` and

it will install all the files of facebook `'FBSDKCoreKit','FBSDKLoginKit','FBSDKShareKit'` in to the ios platform

might it will help you too.

Answer (score 1):

This means that you have an error on
App/Plugins/cordova-plugin-facebook4/FacebookConnectPlugin.m

if you go to xcode and check that file , you will see the missing classes. I think that you are using a SDK not supported by the plugin, so I recommend you to change to cordova-plugin-facebook-connect that support last facebook sdks (9.0.0)
https://github.com/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect#readme